# Data does not gets added to database after adding email and password in authorization in firebase through vue.js

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

Data does not get added to database after adding email and password in authorization in Firebase through vue.js.

After:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
```

This doesn't get executed:

```
ref.set({
    alias: this.alias,
    geolocation: null,
    user_id: cred.user.uid
})
```

Email and Password gets added to Authorization. But other fields like alias, geolocation, user_id does not get added to the database.

```js
import slugify from 'slugify'
import db from '@/firebase/init'
import firebase from 'firebase'

export default {
    name: 'Signup',
    data(){
        return {
            email: null,
            password: null,
            alias: null,
            feedback: null,
            slug: null,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        signup() {
            if(this.alias && this.email && this.password) {
                this.feedback = null
                this.slug = slugify(this.alias, {
                    replacement: '-',
                    remove: /[$*_+~.()'"!\-:@]/g,
                    lower: true
                })
                let ref = db.collection('users').doc(this.slug)
                ref.get().then(doc => {
                    if(doc.exists){
                        this.feedback = 'This alias already exists'        
                    }
                    else {
                        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
                        .then(cred => {
                            ref.set({
                                alias: this.alias,
                                geolocation: null,
                                user_id: cred.user.uid
                            })
                        }).then(() => {
                            this.$router.push({ name: 'GMap' })
                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                            console.log(err)
                            this.feedback = err.message
                        })
                    }
                })
            } else {
                this.feedback = 'You must enter all fields'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors do you receive in the console when you try and make a new account? It may be a small problem like one of those fields being undefined.

Comment: No errors at all. I get redirected to the GMap route and when I check the data, only Authorization has email & password and other details does not get stored in the Database in firestore

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to use cloud functions to write to the database on userCreate
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events